# Why does every collision, not just tagged Enemy, activate this if statement? C# in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making this spaceshooter game, and I want the Damage funcion to be called when the player hits the enemy. But for some reason every collision, also with lasers and powerups, will call the damage function. Does anybody where the problem lies? I am very new to Unity, C# and programming in general, so the problem might be obvious.
This is the code I am using. In case you need more details or more code just ask me.

```
        void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
        {
            if (other.tag == "Enemy") ;
            {
                Damage();
            }
        }
```

Sorry for bad English btw, I'm not native and still in highschool.

Comment: Remove the semicolon after the `if` condition

Comment: ^This is the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much. Such a dumb error, and it was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty simple bug. You have an unneeded semicolon (;) after your if statement. This ends the scope of the if statement before the {} block, so it runs the Damage() function every time.

```
if (other.tag == "Enemy") ;
```

should be

```
if (other.tag == "Enemy")
```

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple bug, and it was driving me crazy.